# Unknown encoder 'libwebp'

Tags: ffmpeg, centos

I am FFMPEG installed on Cent Os 7.8. I am trying to convert the video into animation in webp format but It says

Unknown encoder `'libwebp'`

I want to know how can I install libwebp and enable it

This is what my ffmpeg shows

```
    ffmpeg version 3.4.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
    configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --
datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --disable-encoder=libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
    libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
    libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
    libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
    libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
    libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
    libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
    libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
    libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
    libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

I couldn't find libwebp in it.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

- Download an already compiled `ffmpeg`. All of the executables linked to on the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page support libwebp.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile and Install ffmpeg on CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos). You'll need to install the *libwebp-devel* package and add `--enable-libwebp` to the `ffmpeg` configure line.

Comment: If I choose the second option then how can I add it in the configure line? where can I find the configuration file?

Comment: @mynameisbutt You would add `--enable-libwebp` in [this section](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos#FFmpeg) with all the other `--enable`s.